# sh.exe.stackdump file in Source Tree/git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

One of my repositories suddenly show `sh.exe.stackdump` file as instaged.

What is this file and what do I do with it?  Do I just ignore it?

I tried updating embedded git in Source Tree

```
Tools > Options > Git > click on Update Embedded Git
```

as someone suggested but that did nothing, the file is still there

I also tried to use system git

```
Tools > Options > Git > click on Use System Git
```

but that did nothing.

Uninstalling SourceTree did not change anything either

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this problem for months, I tried numerous Internet solutions (PATH fix, reinstall), today I finally managed to solve: The problem was a conflict with **Comodo Internet Security** (Comodo Firewall in my case), when I removed it, the error disappeared immediately.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4556

And here how to preserve the Comodo: https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-766-11485-Miscellaneous-Settings.html#shellcode_injection&_ga=2.241892802.1773408369.1525225022-41239862.1525101797

My original answer:
[sh.exe.stackdump when use git stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823054/sh-exe-stackdump-when-use-git-stash#answer-51028459)

Comment: Include all of the relevant information as a part of your answer, not as a link

Comment: All relevant information was there, anyway, I put the direct links where I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try and:

- reinstall SourceTree
- Install the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) and make sure your %PATH% references it
- Use the System Git then.

Comment: File is there still.  What is it?  Do I just ignore it?

Comment: @pixel No, if it is untracked, you should delete it, and check it does not come back.

Comment: How do I check it does not come bank?  I have no idea why and how it showed up at first place.  I don't know what it is either.

Comment: @pixel Simply continue working in that repo( add/commit/push): after a few operation, check if that file has been generated again.